# DB Schema for online market

Tags: schema

I'm just search for advice. I have [image: this db]. Every Product type has its own set of characteristics. The Big problem is when someone add new Product type, aslo need create new table with product characteristics. I can see only one solution without DBA, saving all products characteristics in one table but this is not good.

Comment: I think I can guess how adding a new product type can be a problem but I can also imagine scenarios where it's not. Why is it a big problem in *your* case? Could you elaborate on that a little in your question? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is any creation of tables in production. As programmist I can easily create any tables, but in production db has to have hard sceleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Entity-Attribute-Value" or EAV design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) allows you to create new attributes for products without modifying the database structure.

[Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) has an excellent article on the advantages and pitfalls of this design [over on SQLBlog.org](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway).

A simplified example, based on your requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
    ProductID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Products
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ProductName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.AttributeTypes
(
    AttributeTypeID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_AttributeTypes
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , AttributeTypeName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductAttributes
(
    ProductAttributeID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ProductAttributes
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ProductID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_ProductAttributes_ProductID
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.Products(ProductID)
    , AttributeTypeID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_ProductAttributes_AttributeTypeID
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.AttributeTypes(AttributeTypeID)
    , AttributeValue nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

This will insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductName)
VALUES ('Oven Trays')
    , ('Cars')
    , ('Vacuum Cleaners');

INSERT INTO dbo.AttributeTypes (AttributeTypeName)
VALUES ('Manufacturer')
    , ('purpose')
    , ('diameter');

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductAttributes (ProductID, AttributeTypeID, AttributeValue)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Farberware')
    , (2, 1, 'General Motors')
    , (3, 1, 'Hoover')
    , (1, 2, 'cookies')
    , (2, 2, 'driving')
    , (3, 2, 'cleaning floors')
    , (1, 3, '12"');
```

This shows how we get desired output:

```
SELECT p.ProductName
    , att.AttributeTypeName
    , pa.AttributeValue
FROM dbo.Products p
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductAttributes pa ON p.ProductID = pa.ProductID
    INNER JOIN dbo.AttributeTypes att ON pa.AttributeTypeID = att.AttributeTypeID
ORDER BY p.ProductName
    , att.AttributeTypeName;
```

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║   ProductName   ║ AttributeTypeName ║ AttributeValue  ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Cars            ║ Manufacturer      ║ General Motors  ║
║ Cars            ║ purpose           ║ driving         ║
║ Oven Trays      ║ diameter          ║ 12"             ║
║ Oven Trays      ║ Manufacturer      ║ Farberware      ║
║ Oven Trays      ║ purpose           ║ cookies         ║
║ Vacuum Cleaners ║ Manufacturer      ║ Hoover          ║
║ Vacuum Cleaners ║ purpose           ║ cleaning floors ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```